# What language should i learn to create desktop application?

Tags: c, user-interface, desktop-application

I'm new to programming, I'm learning alone,I'm not attendant to any school.
I began my programming on C, I've been learning it from S.Prata C Primer Plus.
I'm in the middle of the book like 320/680 pages.
My goal that i set myself is to create advanced calorie calculator with local database :D
I want it to be on windows with a nice GUI and many options that I'll provide into it. 
What languages do I have to learn next after C to finish my project?

Comment: This is rather broad and off topic for Stackoverflow. However, if you already know C you could look into [GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what desktop you are writing for. Windows, C#. Mac, Swift or Objective-C. Linux, you can use Python.

If you want to write a single program that will work on both Windows and Mac, you want to learn a windowing language like QML, and use C++ with it.

So it's not as simple as 'a' language.

Comment: I'd like to create it for windows for my own needs.I'll learn c++ and then c#. Thanks for help :)

Comment: ...and of course you can always make it a webapp.